# Why does SFTP prompt for a password when trying to connect to azure storage that should only accept RSA keys?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, azure, ssh-keys

When I try to make an SFTP connection to an azure storage account using RSA keys azure still prompts me for a password. This problem occurs only on my laptop which is running Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS on WSL. Connecting from an CentOS server works fine.

When looking into the debug logging I find the following:

```bash
$ sftp -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa <storage_account>.<user>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version AzureSSH_1.0.0
debug1: compat_banner: no match: AzureSSH_1.0.0
...
debug1: Found key in /home/<me>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after # blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after # blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<me>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ASUPERLONGSTRINGIN64BITIGUESS explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/<me>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ASUPERLONGSTRINGIN64BITIGUESS explicit
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Next authentication method: password
<storage_account>.<user>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net's password:
```

I think this line is the problem: `debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm`

The logging from my server that works (with the same key).

```bash
$ sftp -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa <storage_account>.<user>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version AzureSSH_1.0.0
debug1: no match: AzureSSH_1.0.0
...
debug1: Found key in /home/<me>@<my_server>/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after # blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after # blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ./.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <storage_account>.<user>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net ([#.#.#.#]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Connected to <storage_account>.<user>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net.
sftp>
```

Does someone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but the root cause is still not clear to me.

There was a hint in this line: `debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm`

For some reason AzureSSH_1.0.0 doesn't recognize RSA keys from certain (new) SSH clients. The solution is to explicitly set the key type like this:

```bash
$ sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o 'PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa' <storage_account>.<user>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net
```

Or set it in your `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```bash
Host <storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net
    HostName <storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
    User <storage_account>.<user>
```

Comment: It recognizes the keys themselves but not the _signatures_ (proofs of private key possession) made using those keys. https://superuser.com/a/1769058/1686, https://superuser.com/a/1683712/1686, etc.